# Is there a method to solve the diophantine equation of the form $x^2 - ay +1 =0$, where $a \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As the title says, is there a standard method to obtain a set of solutions for the Diophantine equation? Thank you.

Comment: Read Hilbert's Tenth Problem (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HilbertsProblems.html).

Comment: @Sanath Devalapurkar I am asking for this particular one and not a method for any equation.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to solve for $a$? Any factor of $x^2+1$ will do...

Comment: @chubakueno a is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

We have $x^2+1=ay$. The equation is solvable iff $a|x^2+1 \iff x^2\equiv-1 \pmod a$. Now, we need that [every prime factor of $a$ is $\equiv 1 \pmod 4$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_quadratic_reciprocity#.E2.88.921_and_the_first_supplement).  Assuming that is true, we can happily apply our favorite method(say, computing the square root of $-1$ modulo each prime factor with  [this](http://www.mersennewiki.org/index.php/Modular_Square_Root) and then combining them using CRT) to compute the square roots of $-1\pmod a$. Finally, we set $y=\frac{x^2+1}{a}$

Comment: Thanks. Can this be done without factoring a?

Comment: @user141712 Invariably we need to get the square root of $-1 \mod a$. You can apply the algorithm of your choice to do so, in this case the most common method to get the square root of a number are the methods listed. I don't know of an algorithm that gets the square root modulo a composite number directly, but I am not omniscient :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=z^2$. Then, the equation simplifies to $x^2-nz^2=-1$. This can be solved by using continued fractions. Note, however, that this introduces extraneous solutions, which must be removed. The positive solutions are obtained by taking the odd powers of the fundamental solution. (Note that this is solvable iff the exists a primitive Pythagorean triple $(A,B,C)$ and positive integers $a,b,c$ such that $n=a^2+b^2$ and $|aA-bB|=1$.)